# What does this piece of code do? What is the purpose? Regarding struct

Tags: c++, struct

I am not understanding this code. It is for a task I have been given to improve a program that accepts strings and sorts words and removes duplicates etc. This struct code takes in the words from stdin.

```
struct Word
{
  char * data;
  int count;

  Word ( char * data_ ) :
    data( ::_strdup(data_) )
  {}
  
  Word () :
    data((char *)"")
  {}
 
};
```

But the syntax on this code is a bit alien to me and I can't work out what its doing. Some pointers to read up on or directions where to figure it out would be much appreciated.

It's more specifically the overloading(?) areas that take the buffer and do something with it.

```
  Word ( char * data_ ) :
    data( ::_strdup(data_) )
```

not sure what this is doing, espcially the colon syntax.

And also this bit

```
  Word () :
    data((char *)"")
```

Comment: It's broken so don't use it. It doesn't `free` the resource when it's destroyed. Make it use a `std::string` instead. `data((char *)"")` also looks pretty scary.

Comment: Ted is right, there's parts missing that make it not very good. But assuming you only care about the construction part, it looks like you're trying to provide two ways to initialize the object.

Comment: If you were to read something, find Stroustrup's book, something like this will be covered in the first few chapters.

Comment: There's nothing in the shown code that you will not find fully explained in every introductory C++ textbook. Do you know what classes are? Constructors, etc...? Unfortunately stackoverflow.com is not a replacement for a C++ textbook. Furthermore, the shown code is poorly designed, violates const-correctness, and also uses nonstandard C++ functions. . In short, you'll need to figure this out yourself, most likely with your textbook's help. Feel free to ask ***specific*** questions if there's something in your textbook's explanation that's unclear to you.

Comment: This is worst mixture of `C` a and `C++`. This way you will not learn well any of those two.

Comment: `(char *)""` is not valid, it converts a string literal to `char *`. Adding `(char *)` in front of `""` is just silencing the warning a compiler would show for that, but doesn't make it valid. Having a pointer that (depending on which constructor is called)  either points to data allocated with `malloc` or a string literal is really bad, the one allocated with `malloc` has to be freed, the other one must not be freed.

Comment: You could use a `std::map<std::string, int>` to use the `std::string` as a key and store the incrementing count in the second member.  That'd improve the program a lot right there.

Answer (score 0):

First: this code is broken. For your talk you will need to fix a memory leak.

This is a strict with two constructors. The first constructor takes a C-style string (char * data_) and makes a copy of it on the heap (::_strdup) and stores it in the member variable "data". The colon in the constructor before the constructor body signifies the start of an initializer list ( I recommend you Google that).

The second constructor copies the pointer to a C-string literal representing the empty string and stores it in the member variable data.

This code is broken because of the first constructor is called you need to free data, but if the second constructor is called, calling free on it would likely cause your program to crash because it doesn't point to a C-string allocated on the heap.

As another commenter pointed out, this struct should just be replaced by a std::string which correctly does what this struct appears to be attempting to do.